# How to show that $A_t := \bigg\{u \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid u_1 = 0 \text{ and } \sum_{i=1}^n \lvert u_{i+1}-u_i \rvert \le t \bigg\}$ is closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I am having trouble with the following exercise:

> For $t > 0$ consider the set
>
> $$A_t := \bigg\{u \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid u_1 = 0 \text{ and } \sum_{i=1}^n \lvert u_{i+1}-u_i \rvert \le t  \bigg\}.$$
>
> Show that $A_t$ is closed.

I do not see how to prove this. I tried using the topological definition of closedness: We consider some $x \in A_t^C$ and we need to show that we can find some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $U_\varepsilon(x) \subset A_t^C$. By definition of $A_t$ we see that $x$ should be of the form $x_0 \ne 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n \lvert x_{i+1}-x_i \rvert > t$.

Unfortunately I do not see how to keep going from here. Could you please give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by
$$ f(u_1,\ldots,u_n)=\left(u_1,\sum_{i=1}^n|u_{i+1}-u_i| \right)$$
then $f$ is continuous and $A_t=f^{-1}(\{0\}\times [0,t])$. Since $\{0\}\times[0,t]$, is closed, the same goes for $A_t$.